# libmpdclient: detect lost connection to MPD daemon

Tags: c, mpd

I'm writing a plugin for my statusbar to print MPD state, currently using the [libmpdclient](http://www.musicpd.org/libs/libmpdclient/) library. It has to be robust to properly handle lost connections in case MPD is restarted, but simple checking with `mpd_connection_get_error` on existing [mpd_connection](http://www.musicpd.org/doc/libmpdclient/structmpd__connection.html) object does not work – it can detect the error only when the initial `mpd_connection_new` fails.

This is a simplified code I'm working with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <mpd/client.h>

int main(void) {
    struct mpd_connection* m_connection = NULL;
    struct mpd_status* m_status = NULL;
    char* m_state_str;

    m_connection = mpd_connection_new(NULL, 0, 30000);

    while (1) {
        // this check works only on start up (i.e. when mpd_connection_new failed),
        // not when the connection is lost later
        if (mpd_connection_get_error(m_connection) != MPD_ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not connect to MPD: %s\n", mpd_connection_get_error_message(m_connection));
            mpd_connection_free(m_connection);
            m_connection = NULL;
        }

        m_status = mpd_run_status(m_connection);
        if (mpd_status_get_state(m_status) == MPD_STATE_PLAY) {
            m_state_str = "playing";
        } else if (mpd_status_get_state(m_status) == MPD_STATE_STOP) {
            m_state_str = "stopped";
        } else if (mpd_status_get_state(m_status) == MPD_STATE_PAUSE) {
            m_state_str = "paused";
        } else {
            m_state_str = "unknown";
        }
        printf("MPD state: %s\n", m_state_str);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

When MPD is stopped during the execution of the above program, it segfaults with:

```
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007fb2fd9557e0 in mpd_status_get_state () from /usr/lib/libmpdclient.so.2
```

The only way I can think of to make the program safe is to establish a new connection in every iteration, which I was hoping to avoid. But then what if the connection is lost between individual calls to `libmpdclient` functions? How often, and more importantly *how exactly*, should I check if the connection is still alive?

Answer (score 2):

The only way I could find that really works (beyond reestablishing a connection with each run) is using the [idle command](http://www.musicpd.org/doc/libmpdclient/idle_8h.html).  If `mpd_recv_idle` (or `mpd_run_idle`) returns 0, it is an error condition, and you can take that as a cue to free your connection and run from there.
It's not a perfect solution, but it does let you keep a live connection between runs, and it helps you avoid segfaults (though I don't think you can completely avoid them, because if you send a command and mpd is killed before you recv it, I'm pretty sure the library still segfaults).  I'm not sure if there is a better solution.  It would be fantastic if there was a reliable way to detect if your connection was still alive via the API, but I can't find anything of the sort.  It doesn't seem like libmpdclient is well-built for very long-lived connections that have to deal with mpd instances that go up and down over time.

Another lower-level option is to use sockets to interact with MPD through [its protocol](http://www.musicpd.org/doc/protocol/) directly, though in doing that you'd likely reimplement much of libmpdclient itself anyway.

EDIT:  Unfortunately, the idle command does block until something happens, and can sit blocking for as long as a single audio track will last, so if you need your program to do other things in the interim, you have to find a way to implement it asynchronously or in another thread.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "conn" is a connection created with "mpd_connection_new":

```
if (mpd_connection_get_error(conn) == MPD_ERROR_CLOSED) {
    // mpd_connection_get_error_message(conn)
    // will return "Connection closed by the server"
}
```

You can run this check after almost any libmpdclient call, including "mpd_recv_idle" or (as per your example) "mpd_run_status".

I'm using libmpdclient 2.18, and this certainly works for me.